# What is the use of mydatabase.db in Hive?

Tags: hive

Just now I start reading about Hive and I have a doubt. When I create a database called 'xyz' in Hive, it creates a folder 'xyz.db'. Anyway Hive is using metastore_db to store the table schema. Then what is the use of this 'xyz.db' folder?

Regards
Sivagururaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default directory where the data files for the tables are stored on HDFS.

metastore_db is an external db (mysql, postgres, derby, etc..) which stores the table schema to be used to read the files in `xyz.db`.